# Ember link-to on table row issue

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to use a link-to around a whole table row. Here is how I am setting it up:

```
{{#each model as |servicerequest|}}
    {{#link-to 'servicerequest.detail' servicerequestId tagName="tr"}}
        <td>
        {{servicerequest.status}}
        </td>
        <td>
        <strong>{{servicerequest.srdescription}}</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
         {{servicerequest.priority}}
        </td>
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

I see the data but it is not a clickable link, just text. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using divs with flexbox and proper styling. Tables are not the best option and are a quite ancient solution already.

Some examples:

https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx

Answer (score 0):

The link-to will not generate a href attribute if you use any tagName other than `a`. See [changes](https://zoom.us/j/8979761066) in 1.4.0.

So maybe try putting the link-to helper around the  tags.